# No windows console found. Are you running cmd.exe? What is exact reason for this error?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, aws-cli

I created a classic CI pipeline in azure devops to run aws commands using "AWS CLI template". I used "aws configure sso" command in AWS CLI but when I run the pipeline, I'm getting this error- No windows console found. Are you running cmd.exe? And the process failed with exit code 255" what is this error exactly and please anyone tell me, how can I remove it?

Answer (score 1):

What is the OS of the agent you used to run the CI pipeline? Windows, Linux or macOS?

According to the introduction about the extension "[**AWS Toolkit for Azure DevOps**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AmazonWebServices.aws-vsts-tools)", the **AWS CLI** task is only available on Windows agent.

Looks like this task can only call the `cmd.exe` to execute the command. And the `cmd.exe` is only available on Windows.

[image]

**[UPDATE]**

What agent did you use? Microsoft-hosted Windows agent, or self-hosted Windows agent?

Please make sure the `cmd.exe` has been installed on the Windows machine, and has been added to the system environment variable.

You can run the bash command **`printenv`** to list all the system environment variables, then check if this **`COMSPEC=C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe`** is listed.

If the `cmd.exe` also has been installed correctly on your local Windows machine, you can try directly executing the related AWS CLI command on you local Windows machine to see if the same issue occurs. If the same issue occurs, the problem should occur on the AWSCLI itself.

If the issue only occurs when using the AWS CLI task, the issue should occur on the task itself, you can report this issue on the [**Q & A**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AmazonWebServices.aws-vsts-tools&ssr=false#qna) tab of the extension on Marketplace.

Comment: Hi @Bright Ran-MSFT, The OS of my agent is "windows". But, Do you know exactly, why error occurs?

Comment: Hello @Bright Ran-MSFT, Thank you so much for your reply. I have cmd.exe in my PC, I checked it correctly. And I can run the aws commands from powershell/command line. So I think it's the problem with AWS CLI task in Azure(and also azure devops supports only awscli version-1). And I should not report this issue on the Q/A tab. So please, let me know, if you know the solution or any suggestions.

Comment: Hi @Mansa, According to your reply. I think the issue is most likely related to the AWS CLI task itself. Due to this extension is developed by Amazon, I recommend that you should report the issue to the appropriate develop team of Amazon for more support.

I have created an issue ([aws/aws-toolkit-azure-devops#406](https://github.com/aws/aws-toolkit-azure-devops/issues/406)) to help you report the problem to the appropriate develop team on the GitHub repository of this extention, you can follow this issue and add you comments to it.